# Length Of The Shortest Path Touching 2 Sides And 2 Vertices Of A Triangle.

Tags: geometry, inequality, contest-math

In $\triangle BAC$, points $D$ and $E$ lie on $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$ respectively. Let $C_1$ be the reflection of $C$ across $\overline{AB}$, and let $C_2$ be the reflection of $C_1$ across $\overline{AC}$. Prove that the quantity $BE+DE+CD$ is minimized when it is equal to $C_2B$.

This is a problem I contrived from problem 20 on the 2014 AMC12A. It can be solved via a "simple application of the triangle inequality".

The inequalities I set up are:
$BE$ $+$ $ED$ $>$ $BD$,
$CD$ $+$ $ED$ $>$ $CE$,
$AE$ $+$ $ED$ $>$ $AD$,
$AD$ $+$ $ED$ $>$ $AE$,
$AB$ + $AC_2$ > $BC_2$

I then added up the first four to get $BD + CE + 4ED + AE + AD > AE + CE + AD + BD = AB + AC = AB + AC_2 > BC_2$

So $BE+ CD + 4ED + AE + AD > BC_2$, except what I want to prove is that $BE + CD + ED \geq BC_2$

From this point I am stuck. I do not know which inequalities I need to create and combine in order to solve the problem, though I assume there is an inequality I am missing that would allow me to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Can you see that you need to show $BE + ED_1 + D_1C_2 \geq BC_2$?

Comment: Also note that you cannot always achieve the equality. For example, if $\angle A$ is obtuse and hence the reflections are on $AB$ extended and $AC$ extended, you cannot achieve the equality.

Answer (score 1):

This setup is the milkmaid problem, where the sum of distances is minimized by using reflection.

**Hint:** $BE + ED + DC = BE + ED + DC_1 = BE + ED_2 + D_2 C_2 \leq BC_2$.

Now, what do you think $D_2$ is?